# How to etree findall() on many levels

Tags: python-3.x, findall, xml.etree, draw.io

I try to manipulate an diagrams.net (formerly draw.io) not compressed XML exported drawing.

Cables can be hooked up to elements and I want to get a cables-list.
I do a search for all cables by testing if the element has `source` and `target` attributes. Then I compare the `id's` of both with the full list of elements to find the connected label in `value`.

That works great until someone tries to add an "addon-tag". After that (even if it's deleted), the element gets wrapped in a `<object>` that has the `id` attribute but the `source` and `target` attribute stay in a child node called  like this:

before:

```
<mxCell id="ferXMembXyNwfAPwV5vA-22" value="" style="..endless list" edge="1" parent="1" source="ferXMembXyNwfAPwV5vA-8" target="ferXMembXyNwfAPwV5vA-18">
  <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
    <mxPoint x="540" y="520" as="sourcePoint" />
    <mxPoint x="700" y="520" as="targetPoint" />
  </mxGeometry>
</mxCell>
```

after:

```
<object label="" id="ferXMembXyNwfAPwV5vA-53">
  <mxCell style="..endless long list" edge="1" parent="1" source="ferXMembXyNwfAPwV5vA-42" target="ferXMembXyNwfAPwV5vA-51">
    <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
      <mxPoint x="660" y="340" as="sourcePoint" />
      <mxPoint x="770" y="360" as="targetPoint" />
    </mxGeometry>
  </mxCell>
</object>
```

this `findall` works for normal `mxCell` formated to find `id`, `source` and `target` elements:

`list_of_mxCell_elements = root.findall(root_node,".//*[@source][@target]")`

and this for `objects` elements id's:

`list_of_objects_elements = root.findall(root_node,".//*[@source][@target]/..")`

But how can I access the `mxCell` element from the `list_of_objects_elements`, so I can get hold of `source` and `target` id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by my own.

After findall 'elements' i iterate over the list of elements and just do another findall on each cable element i got.

It looks somewhat like this:

```
list_of_objects_elements = root.findall(root_node,'.//*[@source][@target]/..')
for cable in list_of_objects_elements:
    for mxCell in cable.findall('./*[@source][@target]'):
```

Note the slighly different findall path:

This makes an search for source & target in `<mxCells>` while passing back the next higher element `<object>` from root.

`.//*[@source][@target]/..`

`./*[@source][@target]`

While the lower searches for source & target in only one element deeper than `<object>`

To me those paths are still a Mindblow.